# Is it possible to stream video to browser using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Environment is an ASP.NET MVC Website using .NET Framework 4.6.1. hosted in Azure.

The requirement is to stream a video file (myvideofile.mp4) stored on a Sharepoint site to external users authenticated by our web site but not registered in our Azure AD.

I have tested the basic concept with code that can stream from an external open access url via our website controller (acting as a proxy) to the client browser. No problems.

For the real situation:

1. I can retrieve the Sharepoint url for myvideofile.mp4 using graph API. However, the MVC controller cannot access this url because the Graph API token (full rights to the Sharepoint tenant via API) does not provide access to the Sharepoint url.
2. I can retrieve the file's authenticated "Download URL" using Microsoft Graph, but this link always downloads the file. it does not allow streaming.
3. I attempted to create a shared anonymous link for myvideofile.mp4 using CreateLink("view", "anonymous") via the Graph API but the Sharepoint Admin has anonymous links disabled and is unwilling to remove this restriction.
4. I tested accessing the sharepoint site from a powershell script using login credentials (with the hope I could later convert this to method to code) using  "Connect-SPOService -url https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $credentials" but it errors saying "the web site does not support Sharepoint Online credentials". I believe this can be supported if the Sharepoint Admin allows "Apps that don't use modern authentication", but the jury is still out on whether he is willing to do this or not.
5. I can download the contents of the file using Graph API such as :

   ```
   return await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].Items[FileId].Content.Request().GetAsync();
   ```

but this downloads the entire file before continuing. It apparently cannot be streamed to the client browser.

Does anyone know how, or if it is even possible, to immediately stream a file to the client using the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: I haven't heard that you can do the above. Instead of MS Graph, you need to think about using Microsoft Stream service which is meant for it. Here's the link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/microsoft-stream

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dev. 

My investigations have led me to the same conclusion. I can download the the Sharepoint file in chunks using range headers, and in mp4 format rather than Gzip using the "Accept-Encoding: identity"  header and then stream these chunks to the Video Tag on the client page. However, even though I can see the data accumulating in the browser, the video tag will not display the content unless the entire file has already been received. It looks like this approach is just not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft Stream does not appear to be an option for us because it still requires authentication to Sharepoint to access the video files and not all our users can be authenticated in Azure AD, even though they may be authenticated by our web site for restricted access to some video files on Sharepoint.

It seems to me that the only viable option is to convince the Sharepoint Admin to enable "Sharepoint Online Credentials" as mentioned in item 4 above and use the Sharepoint built-in video streaming capabilities.

Comment: Did you find a way? This seems to still be an issue

Comment: Try using the download link that you have mentioned at 2, and remove header "content-disposition"